# How does ultimate donations work when you donate after you've already donated?

Tags: virtual-beggar

I've made the ultimate donation once and I chose to boost the bus money twice and the worker money once. I'm wondering how it works when you donate a second time. I know that you get 3 more boosts to choose from, but do the boosts stack?

I'm playing version 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the donations continue on.  I've done the Ultimate donation quite a few times now and you keep getting three dots to spread out.